# Ignoring higher order terms in solving a system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

I have used Series & Normal commands a lot to ignore higher order terms in final results. However, I have no idea how to solve a system of equations ignoring higher order terms. For example, consider a system of equations

```
Solve[{(a)x^2+(b-a)y^2+(b^2)xy+(ab)x+(a+2b)y+(ab^2)f== 
0, (b)x^2+(4a)y^2+(a^2)xy+(a)x+(b)y+(b-a)F == 0}, {x, y}].
```

Can we solve this system of equations for x and y, ignoring any second or higher order terms in a and b? Of course I can erase such higher order terms in the first place like

```
Solve[{(a)x^2+(b-a)y^2+(a+2b)y== 
0, (b)x^2+(4a)y^2+(a)x+(b)y+(b-a)F == 0}, {x, y}],
```

but even in that case the solution x and y might have higher order terms in a and b. What I want is to **ignore higher order terms in solving a system of equations and get the final results linear in a and b**

I would really appreciate if you help me out with this...! (But please don't care about the above specific example too much since I have just made it up randomly.)

Comment: Please checkand correct your equations: `xy` should be `x y`? `ab` should be `a b`?`f`should be `F`! If the order   `O[a] equals O[b]`you can solve your problem by substituting `{a -> eps a, b -> eps b}`  and seriesexpansion `eps->0`

Comment: Are you saying `a` and `b` are small, so `a a` or `a b` are really small? What is the justification for ignoring your HOTs?  It is possible to have a system equations be 'ill conditioned' such that the HOTs are important to the result. One must be careful.

Comment: 1) Oh, sorry for simple mistakes... Yes, xy and ab should be x y and a b, and F should be f. I will try!
2) Yes, I am trying to make any second or higher order terms consisting of a and b small enough, since the full system of equation is too complicated even for mathematica to be solved. I will try and see if something weird thing happens as you said!

Comment: To Neumann. In fact, my original system of equations is so complicated, so Mathematica can't solve it exactly. So I want Mathematica solve this perturbatively with respect to small variables (for example, with respect to a and b above), within Solve command. Can we do that...?